# How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I want to cycle through the objects contained in an array and change the properties of each one. If I do this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){

console.log(myArray[j]);

}
```

The console should bring up every object in the array, right? But in fact it only displays the first object. if I console log the array outside of the loop, all the objects appear so there's definitely more in there.

Anyway, here's the next problem. How do I access, for example Object1.x in the array, using the loop?

```
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){

console.log(myArray[j.x]);

}
```

This returns "undefined." Again the console log outside the loop tells me that the objects all have values for "x". How do I access these properties in the loop?

I was recommended elsewhere to use separate arrays for each of the properties, but I want to make sure I've exhausted this avenue first.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your array? The first code snippet seems correct.

Comment: `j` is a number. You defined it at the top of your loop.

Comment: Maybe `myArray` is not really just an array after all??

Comment: we need more info on how myArray is constructed

Comment: With all following answers and having an accepted answer no one explains why the problem occurs and how to resolve it with for loop. `#forEach` works. But the question was about for loop.

Comment: The simple syntax error that caused the problem in the second part of the original question is called out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626812/5003971) (`myArray[j.x]` should be `myArray[j].x`). A regular `for` loop works just fine, if the syntax is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 506, accepted):

Use forEach its a built-in array function. [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
yourArray.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var x = arrayItem.prop1 + 2;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: @DoryZidon:  forEach not support break or stop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Note that it is important that you really do have an array. If you got `yourArray` from something like `document.getElementsByClassName` that would be an HTMLCollection, not an array. Then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/using-foreach-on-an-array-from-getelementsbyclassname-results-in-typeerror-und) could be helpful.

Comment: Note: `forEach` is blocking and doesn't support `await`.The `for...of` loop will.

Answer (score 312):

Some use cases of looping through an array in the **functional programming way** in JavaScript:

#### 1. Just loop through an array

```
const myArray = [{x:100}, {x:200}, {x:300}];

myArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log(element.x); // 100, 200, 300
    console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
    console.log(array); // same myArray object 3 times
});
```

Note: Array.prototype.forEach() is not a functional way strictly speaking, as the function it takes as the input parameter is not supposed to return a value, which thus cannot be regarded as a pure function.

#### 2. Check if any of the elements in an array pass a test

```
const people = [
    {name: 'John', age: 23}, 
    {name: 'Andrew', age: 3}, 
    {name: 'Peter', age: 8}, 
    {name: 'Hanna', age: 14}, 
    {name: 'Adam', age: 37}];

const anyAdult = people.some(person => person.age >= 18);
console.log(anyAdult); // true
```

#### 3. Transform to a new array

```
const myArray = [{x:100}, {x:200}, {x:300}];

const newArray= myArray.map(element => element.x);
console.log(newArray); // [100, 200, 300]
```

Note: The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

#### 4. Sum up a particular property, and calculate its average

```
const myArray = [{x:100}, {x:200}, {x:300}];

const sum = myArray.map(element => element.x).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum); // 600 = 0 + 100 + 200 + 300

const average = sum / myArray.length;
console.log(average); // 200
```

#### 5. Create a new array based on the original but without modifying it

```
const myArray = [{x:100}, {x:200}, {x:300}];

const newArray= myArray.map(element => {
    return {
        ...element,
        x: element.x * 2
    };
});

console.log(myArray); // [100, 200, 300]
console.log(newArray); // [200, 400, 600]
```

#### 6. Count the number of each category

```
const people = [
    {name: 'John', group: 'A'}, 
    {name: 'Andrew', group: 'C'}, 
    {name: 'Peter', group: 'A'}, 
    {name: 'James', group: 'B'}, 
    {name: 'Hanna', group: 'A'}, 
    {name: 'Adam', group: 'B'}];

const groupInfo = people.reduce((groups, person) => {
    const {A = 0, B = 0, C = 0} = groups;
    if (person.group === 'A') {
        return {...groups, A: A + 1};
    } else if (person.group === 'B') {
        return {...groups, B: B + 1};
    } else {
        return {...groups, C: C + 1};
    }
}, {});

console.log(groupInfo); // {A: 3, C: 1, B: 2}
```

#### 7. Retrieve a subset of an array based on particular criteria

```
const myArray = [{x:100}, {x:200}, {x:300}];

const newArray = myArray.filter(element => element.x > 250);
console.log(newArray); // [{x:300}]
```

Note: The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

#### 8. Sort an array

```
const people = [
  { name: "John", age: 21 },
  { name: "Peter", age: 31 },
  { name: "Andrew", age: 29 },
  { name: "Thomas", age: 25 }
];

let sortByAge = people.sort(function (p1, p2) {
  return p1.age - p2.age;
});

console.log(sortByAge);
```

[image]

#### 9. Find an element in an array

```
const people = [ {name: "john", age:23},
                {name: "john", age:43},
                {name: "jim", age:101},
                {name: "bob", age:67} ];

const john = people.find(person => person.name === 'john');
console.log(john);
```

[image]

The Array.prototype.find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

#### References

- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: This is a fantastic reference - is this original to this question or do you have something like this hosted elsewhere?

Comment: hi, if I want to show all the name and then do comparison, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @dipgirl, is it something like below?
```const people = [ {name: "john", age:23}, {name: "john", age:43}, {name: "jim", age:101}, {name: "bob", age:67} ];

const sortByAge = people.map(p => {
  console.log(p.name)
  return p
}).sort(function (p1, p2) {
  return p1.age - p2.age;
});

console.log(sortByAge);```

Answer (score 103):

You can use a [for..of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to loop over an array of objects.

```
for (let item of items) {
    console.log(item); // Will display contents of the object inside the array
}
```

One of the best things about `for..of` loops is that they can iterate over more than just arrays. You can iterate over any type of iterable, including maps and objects. Make sure you use a transpiler or something like TypeScript if you need to support older browsers.

If you wanted to iterate over a map, the syntax is largely the same as the above, except it handles both the key and value.

```
for (const [key, value] of items) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

I use `for..of` loops for pretty much every kind of iteration I do in Javascript. Furthermore, one of the coolest things is they also work with async/await as well.

Comment: I prefer this in `async` functions than using `await Promise.all(array.map(async (element) => {` with a separate `try catch`.  A lot cleaner code.

Comment: `For..of` loops are definitely the best. I believe it's something like 90% or so faster than a forEach loop.

Comment: I can't get this to work for an array of files in the Google Apps Script environment. allFiles = getFilesByFolder(this._folderID,SPREADSHEET_MIME_TYPE); for(let file of allFiles){} gives me a "TypeError: allFiles is not iterable" error.

Answer (score 33):

```
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
  console.log(myArray[j].x);
}
```

Comment: That's just the solution for the second question, though.

Answer (score 18):

Here's an example on how you can do it :)

```js
var students = [{
    name: "Mike",
    track: "track-a",
    achievements: 23,
    points: 400,
  },
  {
    name: "james",
    track: "track-a",
    achievements: 2,
    points: 21,
  },
]

students.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  for (var key in item) {
    console.log(item[key])
  }
}
```

Comment: how would you get the value of the `track` property for each element and assign it to a variable to use or interpolate in another part of code?

Answer (score 10):

Looping through an array of objects is a pretty fundamental functionality. This is what works for me.

```js
var person = [];
person[0] = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 60
};

var i, item;

for (i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
  for (item in person[i]) {
    document.write(item + ": " + person[i][item] + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's really simple using the forEach method since ES5+. You can directly change each property of each object in your array.

```
myArray.forEach(function (arrayElem){ 
  arrayElem = newPropertyValue;
});
```

If you want to access a specific property on each object:

```
myArray.forEach(function (arrayElem){ 
      arrayElem.nameOfYourProperty = newPropertyValue;
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
this.data = [{name:"Rajiv", city:"Deoria"},{name:"Babbi", city:"Salempr"},{name:"Brijesh", city:"GKP"}];
for(const n of this.data) {
    console.log(n.name)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`myArray[j.x]` is logically incorrect.

Use `(myArray[j].x);` instead

```
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
  console.log(myArray[j].x);
}
```

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Oh.. I mean j.x is treated as a variable name which is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

```js
const jobs = [
    {
        name: "sipher",
        family: "sipherplus",
        job: "Devops"
    },
    {
        name: "john",
        family: "Doe",
        job: "Devops"
    },
    {
        name: "jim",
        family: "smith",
        job: "Devops"
    }
];

const txt = 
   ` <ul>
        ${jobs.map(job => `<li>${job.name} ${job.family} -> ${job.job}</li>`).join('')}
    </ul>`
;

document.body.innerHTML = txt;
```

Be careful about the back Ticks (`)

Answer (score 5):

This would work. Looping thorough array(yourArray) . Then loop through direct properties of each object (eachObj) .

```
yourArray.forEach( function (eachObj){
    for (var key in eachObj) {
        if (eachObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           console.log(key,eachObj[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer uses normal function. So posting the same code with slight modification using arrow function on forEach

```
  yourArray.forEach(arrayItem => {
      var x = arrayItem.prop1 + 2;
      console.log(x);
  });
```

Also in $.each you can use arrow function like below

```
 $.each(array, (item, index) => {
       console.log(index, item);
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way of iterating through an array of objects (you need to include jQuery library in your document for these).

```
$.each(array, function(element) {
  // do some operations with each element... 
});
```

Comment: Your answer is missing critical information about the need to load jQuery library to use `$.each` method.

Answer (score 3):

Array object iteration, using jQuery,
(use the second parameter to print the string).

```
$.each(array, function(index, item) {
       console.log(index, item);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var c = {
    myProperty: [
        { name: 'this' },
        { name: 'can' },
        { name: 'get' },
        { name: 'crazy' }
    ]
};

c.myProperty.forEach(function(myProperty_element) {
    var x = myProperty_element.name;
    console.log('the name of the member is : ' + x);
})
```

This is one of the ways how I was able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I want to loop and deconstruction assignment at the same time, so code like this: `config.map(({ text, callback })=>add_btn({ text, callback }))`

Answer (score 0):

This might help somebody. Maybe it's a bug in Node.

```
var arr = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];
var c = 0;
```

This doesn't work:

```
while (arr[c].name) { c++; } // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

But this works...

```
while (arr[c]) { c++; } // Inside the loop arr[c].name works as expected.
```

This works too...

```
while ((arr[c]) && (arr[c].name)) { c++; }
```

BUT simply reversing the order does not work. I'm guessing there's some kind of internal optimization here that breaks Node.

```
while ((arr[c].name) && (arr[c])) { c++; }
```

Error says the array is undefined, but it's not :-/ Node v11.15.0

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been long but for anyone else encountering this issue, my problem is that I was looping through an array of arrays containing only one array. Like this:

```
// array snippet (returned from here)
} else {
   callback([results])
}
```

And I was using the array like this

```
for(const result of results){
   console.log(result.x)
}
```

As you can see, the array I wanted to iterate over was actually inside another array. removing the square brackets helped. Node JS and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 12,
    gender: "male",
  },
  {
    name: "Madeline",
    age: 80,
    gender: "female",
  },
  {
    name: "Cheryl",
    age: 22,
    gender: "female",
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
  },
  {
    name: "Suzy",
    age: 4,
    gender: "female",
  },
];
```

If you have an array with objects nested inside, and you want to loop through the properties of the object then you can use that code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i].age)
}
```