# How to merge the two array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to merge the two array of objects using javascript for given data.

```js
var data = [{
  "key": 2000,
  "value": 10000
}, {
  "key": 2001,
  "value": 50000
}];

var data1 = [{
  "key": [2000, 0],
  "value": 1000
}, {
  "key": [2000, 1],
  "value": 1500
}, {
  "key": [2000, 3],
  "value": 2000
}, {
  "key": [2001, 0],
  "value": 2500
}, {
  "key": [2001, 1],
  "value": 3000
}, {
  "key": [2001, 3],
  "value": 4000
}];
```

And finally out put is given below:

```js
var data3 = [{
  "key": 2000,
  "value": 10000,
  children: [{
    "key": [2000, 0],
    "value": 1000
  }, {
    "key": [2000, 1],
    "value": 1500
  }, {
    "key": [2000, 3],
    "value": 2000
  }]
}, {
  "key": 2001,
  "value": 50000,
  children: [{
    "key": [2001, 0],
    "value": 2500
  }, {
    "key": [2001, 1],
    "value": 3000
  }, {
    "key": [2001, 3],
    "value": 4000
  }]
}]
```

Comment: I am tried for the given code:

        function fctnCombine(){var arr=[];
        for(var i in data1){
          var year;var obj={};
          
          if(year==2009){
          
          obj.key=new Date(data1[i].key[0],data1[i].key[1]);
          obj.value=data1[i].value;
         // console.log(obj)
         arr.push(obj);
          }
          
        }
     return arr;
     }

Comment: I will not be the one who will steal to you the pleasure to found a nice algorithm. I will just give you a hint: first with data http://tinyurl.com/l92nboe then inside the loop with data2 http://tinyurl.com/k5duy6l

Comment: Why not use underscore.js

Comment: @kirnp Please check my answer below with the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by iterating over the given 2 arrays using `forEach` loops.

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var data = [{
  "key": 2000,
  "value": 10000
}, {
  "key": 2001,
  "value": 50000
}];

var data1 = [{
  "key": [2000, 0],
  "value": 1000
}, {
  "key": [2000, 1],
  "value": 1500
}, {
  "key": [2000, 3],
  "value": 2000
}, {
  "key": [2001, 0],
  "value": 2500
}, {
  "key": [2001, 1],
  "value": 3000
}, {
  "key": [2001, 3],
  "value": 4000
}];

data.forEach(function(parentObj){  // loop over data
  
  parentObj.children = [];  // initialize the children
  
  data1.forEach(function(childObj){  // loop over data1
    
    if(parentObj["key"] === childObj["key"][0])
      parentObj.children.push(childObj);
    
  });
  
});

console.dir(data);
```

```html
<p>Please check your browser's console now.</p>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626758/586051)

Read up: [`Array.prototype.forEach()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

This iterates as many times as there are objects in the array data1.

Then, in each iteration it will add the object (equal to the variable count) in data1 to data.

Afterwards, it will make the variable data1 undefined.

```js
for(var count = 0; count < data1.length; count++){
    data.push(data1[count]);
}
data1 = undefined;
```

Comment: That's as close as you can get to a merge.

Answer (score 0):

It is multidimensional array. Please check the demo link as follows.
This is demo link click `enter code here`[here] (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/twpUF/)