# Check javascript array of objects property

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have the following javascript array of objects ,I need to check output property if at least  one object is true return true else return false,Can anyone help me to implement that?

```
var array=[{"id":100,"output":false},{"id":100,"output":false},
{"id":100,"output":true}]
```

Comment: use a for-loop :)

Comment: Could you show the code and which is your issue with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) should stop the iteration once one value is found and return a Boolean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The **`some()`** method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var array = [{ "id": 100, "output": false }, { "id": 100, "output": false }, { "id": 100, "output": true }];
    result = array.some(function (a) { return a.output; });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasOneTrue(a){
  return !!a.filter(function(v){
    return v.output;
  }).length;
}

var array = [{"id":100,"output":false}, {"id":100,"output":false}, {"id":100,"output":true}]
console.log(hasOneTrue(array)); // true
```

Comment: you filter all array objects even if `true` in first. better use `some()`

Comment: @Maxx I agree  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could Loop over the array and check every property.

```
var array = [
    {"id":100,"output":false},
    {"id":100,"output":false},
    {"id":100,"output":true}
];

function testOutput ( array ) {
    for (el in array)
        if ( el.output ) return true;

    return false;
}

testOutput (array);
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

fastest + most compatible

```js
var result = false
var json = [{"id":100,"output":false},{"id":100,"output":false},{"id":100,"output":true}]

for(
  var i = json.length;
  !result && i;
  result = json[--i].output
);

console.log("at least one? ", result)
```