# How to iterate through an object stored in an array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can anyone hint me on how to iterate the currencies array using forEach method to get the id and name of the object.

```js
  const currencies = [{
        id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'
      }, {
        id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
      }, {
        id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'
      }];
var populateCurrencies = (currencies)=>{
    currencies.forEach(function(id,name){
     

    }
  }
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: didn't we show you how to do this in your other question?

Comment: Do you want to read id and name in each object?

Comment: Yes @DananjayaAriyasena

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) and [How to iterate over arrays and objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416366)

Comment: thanks so much the post were useful@adiga

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416380/3082296 Change `obj.x`, `obj.y` to `obj.id` and `obj.name`. You can accept the duplicate in that case.

Comment: thanks @adiga  I will delete the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're getting confused because your argument names in your `forEach` callback misrepresent what they actually are.

The first argument of your `.forEach` callback function is the *element* that you're currently iterated on. In your case it is the object you're currently on from your `currencies` array. It is not the `id` like you have named it.

The second argument in your `.forEach` callback is the index, however, you do not need this as all you're after is the object (which is the first argument)

So, if the first argument is the object, you can access its `name` and `id` properties at each iteration using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation).

See example below:

```js
const currencies = [{id:"USD",name:"US Dollars"},{id:"UGX",name:"Ugandan Shillings"},{id:"KES",name:"Kenyan Shillings"},{id:"GHS",name:"Ghanian Cedi"},{id:"ZAR",name:"South African Rand"}];

const populateCurrencies = (currencies) => {
  currencies.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name, obj.id);
  });
}

populateCurrencies(currencies)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add **curly braces** to `extract properties` of item passed to the foreach iterator:

```js
const currencies = [{
        id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'
      }, {
        id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
      }, {
        id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'
      }];

    currencies.forEach(function({id,name}){
     console.log(id,name);

    })
```

Comment: OP looks like a beginner. You should probably avoid destrucutring

Comment: OP was using destructuring argument in the wrong way, so the better fix to gain knowledge were curly braces IMHO. Also mixing const and var is a bad pratice, map is preferred over forEach and extracting an array with the same form of the original one could be useless. I tried only to address him to a working code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currencies = [{
        id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'
      }, {
        id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
      }, {
        id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
      }, {
        id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'
      }];
      
currencies.forEach(currency =>    
     console.log(currency.id + " : " + currency.name)
)
```