# Not able to access below structure one by one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

How can i access this type of structure in java script.
i want to access these emails one by one.

```
          var somevar[];
       console.log(somevar);
     **Below is the result**-:
      [ {email: 'xyz@gmail.com' },
      { email: 'xyz@gmail.com' },
      { email: 'xyz@gmail.com' },
      { email: 'xyz@gmail.com' }]
```

At last i want to send email to the above email ids.Now how to put a loop on somevar to access the list of emails

Comment: You may use `forEach()` or a simple for loop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript function [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you can do it.

Below is working code:

```js
let input = [{
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com'
  }
];

input.forEach(function(ele) {
  console.log(ele.email);
  // send email to each email ID here.
});
```

Comment: this data is coming inside a variable so will it be like this
let input = datavariable;
input.forEach(function(ele) {
  console.log(ele.email);
});
@Mohammad Usman

Comment: @Vishu is my answer satisfy your requirement?