# How to loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

i have a data response from API.

and how to loop this data, cause i only get first data. and this data not array.

```
data = [{"gamename":"game 1","gamelink":"link 1","image_link":"image 1","startfrom":"1"},{"gamename":"game 2","gamelink":"link 2","image_link":"imgae 2","startfrom":"2"}]
```

---

```
var json = response.data[0].games;
console.log(json);

if(Array.isArray(json)){
 console.log('array');
}else{
 console.log('not array');
}

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  console.log('gamename : ' +json[i].gamename+ " - game link: " +json[i].image_link);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you wrapping your JSON, which is already an array, in another array?

Comment: Why do you have array[0][i]? I believe it should be just array[i].                           You're pre-fixing the output to be the first element there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: there are already `[`  and `]` surrounding the two objects.  `[ {}, {} ]` is an array of two objects.  There is no need to wrap it in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Robby Cornelissen has said, you are wrapping your array in another array, which is unnecessary and breaking your code.  Your for loop only iterates over a single element in the outer array.

Also, it is strange for an API response to have a JSON string embedded as a string value within a JSON's property.  You should post how you are retrieving the data.

```js
response={data:[{games:`[{"gamename":"game 1","gamelink":"link 1","image_link":"image 1","startfrom":"1"},{"gamename":"game 2","gamelink":"link 2","image_link":"imgae 2","startfrom":"2"}]`}]}

    var json = response.data[0].games;
    console.log(json);
    
    var array = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(array);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     console.log('gamename : ' +array[i].gamename+ " - game link: " +array[i].image_link);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.map(),array.forEach()

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please answer using code, examples and being as clear and complete in your explanation as possible.

Comment: do you want to know the usage of loops or iterating over objects and arrays

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use foreach or for(on the base of length) or for of loop
Example

```
 for (let element of data) {
   console.log(element );
}
```

And to print data in format you wish, use like

```
for (let element of data) {
   console.log('gamename : ' +element.gamename+ " - game link: " +element.image_link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    console.log(data[i]['gamename']);
    console.log(data[i]['gamelink']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"gamename":"game 1","gamelink":"link 1","image_link":"image 1","startfrom":"1"},{"gamename":"game 2","gamelink":"link 2","image_link":"imgae 2","startfrom":"2"}]
```

as you said if your array look like above one, use below code

```
data.forEach((el)=>console.log(el))
```

you will get every single object in that array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this data from a fetch you need to do `res.json()` in the fetch, an example is:

```js
some data
[
  {"gamename":"game 1","gamelink":"link 1","image_link":"image 1","startfrom":"1"},
  {"gamename":"game 2","gamelink":"link 2","image_link":"imgae 2","startfrom":"2"}
]

fetch("someUrl")
  .then(res => res.json()) // Here you parse the response
  // Here you use forEach to loop in the response, and with destructuring you get the items with the name "gamename" and "gamelink"
  .then(game => game.forEach(({gamename, gamelink}) => console.log(`gamename : ${gamename} - game link: ${gamelink}`)) // Here you log your data, and asumming that this is like the one above, you can do something like this
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your json is already parsed, and you don't need to re-parse it. A lot of http clients will do this if the content type header is `application/json`.

Try:

```
var games = response.data[0].games
for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
 console.log('gamename : ' +games[i].gamename+ " - game link: " +games[i].image_link);
}
```

Comment: when i check, is this array or not. and this is not array.