# javascript why does word return an array and word[0] undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make my website bilingual.
so I would like to iterate my JS object translation. I can iterate it with this code :

```
for (var word of translation) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

but then I get this:

from the moment I use this code I undefined

```
for (var word of translation) {
    console.log(word[0]);
}
```

this is my object model

```
    translation = [ 
      { English : [ ["English" , "engels"], ["lblEng",""] ]}, 
      {dutch : [["dutch" , "nederlands"], ["lblNl",""]]},
      { second : [["second","seconde"], ["sec",""]]},
      {minut : [["minut", "minut"],["min",""]]},
      { hour : [["hour","uur"],["h",""]]},
      { day :[ ["day", "dag"],["d",""]]}, 
      { to : [["to", "naar"],["to",""]]},
      { from : [["from", "van"],["from",""]]}
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: According to your example, `word` will be an *object*. None of the objects in your array have a property `0`, so `word[0]` will indeed return `undefined`. All objects have different properties. `word.English` would work for the first one, but not the second one. Since you are not explaining what output you want to get I don't know how to help.

Comment: You might want to use `Object.values(word)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`for...of` interates over the values in your array, i.e. the objects.  For example the first iteration, `word` = `{ English : [ ["English" , "engels"], ["lblEng",""] ]}`

So when you do `word[0]` its `undefined` as there is no `0` property in that `word` object

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var word of translation) {
    console.log(word[0]);
}
```

The variable `word` will have assigned an object as follow:

```
{ English : [ ["English" , "engels"], ["lblEng",""] ]}
```

So, `word[0]` return `undefined` because the objects don't have a property `0`.

Probably, what you really want to do is the following:

```js
const translation = [ 
  { English : [ ["English" , "engels"], ["lblEng",""] ]}, 
  {dutch : [["dutch" , "nederlands"], ["lblNl",""]]},
  { second : [["second","seconde"], ["sec",""]]},
  {minut : [["minut", "minut"],["min",""]]},
  { hour : [["hour","uur"],["h",""]]},
  { day :[ ["day", "dag"],["d",""]]}, 
  { to : [["to", "naar"],["to",""]]},
  { from : [["from", "van"],["from",""]]}
];
    
for (let word of translation) {
    // get the keys and values and loop over them.
    Object.entries(word).forEach(([lang, values]) => {
        //values[0] returns the first index, so you can access it as follow:
        let [first] = values;
        console.log(lang, first);
        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for al your reactions / answerds...

Of realy helped me forward,  if took a while to respond becose I was  making an ather partition of my web aplication.