# how to get value in json in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

get response in function node.js

```
[
  {
    instrument_token: '12598786',
    exchange_token: '49214',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000CE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'   
  },
  {
    instrument_token: '12599810',
    exchange_token: '49218',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000PE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'
  }
]
```

How to get only instrument_token in another variable in node

const ObjData = JSON.stringify(response); 
console.log(ObjData.instrument_token);

Result  : undefined

Comment: First of all, please tag Javascript as well.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you clarify please, what exactly are you going to do with the array of objects ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't relevant to NodeJS because thats not a language. You want to ask for Javascript.

Since you don't have a JSON OBject, but instead an ARRAY of those, so you need to iterate over the array in a loop, and in it simply go  = object.instrument_token

```
const yourDataArray = [];
function extractData(thatThingYouGetReturnedThere){
  for (let obj of thatThingYouGetReturnedThere){
    yourDataArray.push(obj.instrument_token)
  }
}
```

That way, after calling the function with your array, you have all the data you want stored as an array in yourDataArray

Comment: how ..give me example demo

Comment: @DevenderJangra there it is. I didn't want to give you the solution since you don't even know what you're asking. Your question contains TWO values with the name that you want to have yet you say as if there only was one

Comment: but obj.instrument_token undefined.how posible

Comment: fixed it. Also flagged your question as the duplicate that it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties here, that's where proper answers are.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I think I follow your question.

Lets do this by example. If I have a variable `foo` which is an array of JSON objects:

```
let foo = [ 
            {
              instrument_token: '12598786',
              exchange_token: '49214',
              tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000CE',
              name: 'AARTIIND'   
            },
            {
              instrument_token: '12599810',
              exchange_token: '49218',
              tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000PE',
              name: 'AARTIIND'
            }
          ]
```

To get any individual key-value object pair out I need to specify the array number I want to access. So to get `instrument_token` from the first object I would do:

```
let bar = foo[0];                              // Now bar contains the first JSON object
let myInstrumentToken = bar.instrument_token;  // Instrument token from the first object
```

Similarly if I want the name from the second object I would do:

```
let bar = foo[1];       // Now bar contains the second JSON object of the array
let myName = bar.name;  // Name from the second object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {
    instrument_token: '12598786',
    exchange_token: '49214',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000CE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'   
  },
  {
    instrument_token: '12599810',
    exchange_token: '49218',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000PE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'
  }
];
let tokenArray =[];
for (let obj of data){
    tokenArray.push(obj.instrument_token)
  }
console.log(tokenArray);  
//It will give you [ '12598786', '12599810' ]  
Hope this is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have :

```
response = [
  {
    instrument_token: '12598786',
    exchange_token: '49214',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000CE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'   
  },
  {
    instrument_token: '12599810',
    exchange_token: '49218',
    tradingsymbol: 'AARTIIND21JAN1000PE',
    name: 'AARTIIND'
  }
]
```

you can do this:

```
response.map(x => x = {instrument_token: x.instrument_token})

/* 
 #### output : 
[
{ instrument_token: "12598786" }, 
{ instrument_token: "12599810" } 
]
*/
```

Was this what you wanted?