# How to access and sort keys in nested objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, nested

I have a nested object like this

```
info ={

"id-1": 
{
name: Jane, 
age: 35, 
experience: "7+",
position: manager, 
 
},

"id-2": 
{
age: 38, 
name: John, 
position: manager, 
experience: "9+", 
},

"id-3": 
{
age: 42, 
experience: "12+", 
position: manager, 
name: Max, 
}
```

and I have a string

```
let myString ="name, age,position, experience"
```

I need to access keys in objects (name, age, position, experience) and sort them according to this string, so keys in the object would be in the same order as in myString, like this:

```
"id-1": 
{
name: Jane, 
age: 35, 
position: manager, 
experience: "7+",
},
```

How can I access keys in the nested objects and sort them in order? When I try to use Object.keys(info)  it returns **id-1, id-2, id-3** not name, age, position, experience. Please help, I can't seem to figure out a way.

Comment: This is an XY Problem since there is no guarantee of order of keys in objects (yet). What higher level problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: Please may you fix the syntax errors in the object example? (e.g. `id-3` and `7+` are not valid)

Comment: Related: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Try using info.entries() or info.values().

Comment: @ucup, when I use info.values it returns object itsel like {
name: Jane, 
age: 35, 
position: manager, 
experience: 7+,
}, not the keys (name, age, position)

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm trying to sort keys in my objects in the same order as in myString

Comment: @alia using `Object.entries` will give you both keys and values

Comment: *I'm trying to sort keys in my objects in the same order as in myString* <-- **But why?** Instead, why not just loop through your objects and manually extract the key values in the order you want to see them? Why do you need the actual sequence of the keys in the objects sorted?

Comment: OK, that is evident from question. My question was more along the lines of ..Why? Explain use case in more detail

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you please share the code how I can do that? I just don't know how to write such a code

Comment: Research how to loop over `Object.keys` and in the loop body, simply extract the properties of the object you are looping over in the order you want them via normal property access.

Comment: I dont get it why you need to order an object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: @ScottMarcus, ok, that's the problem, I don't know how to access keys in a nested object, when I use Object.keys(info) it returns id-1, id-2, id-3 not the keys I need (age, position etc).

Comment: @alia please may you read the question I linked?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I did and it doesn't answer my question on how to access keys of an object in  object.

Answer (score 1):

First, most of the values of your keys are invalid. For example `7+` isn't a `string`, `number` or `boolean` and words like `manager` and `John` will be treated like variables if they don't have quotes around them. So your data needs to be fixed up.

Next, instead of wrapping the objects in an object that only has sequential key names (dashes are illegal syntax in key names unless the key names are quoted by the way), just place all the objects in an Array.

Then, just loop over the objects in the array and manually extract the individual key values you want in the order you want them. There is no need to think about re-sequencing the order that they are stored in.

```js
let info = [ 
  {name: "Jane", age: "35", experience: "7+", position: "manager" },
  {age: "38", name: "John", position: "manager", experience: "9+"},
  {age: "42", experience: "12+", position: "manager", name: "Max"}
];

let keyNames = ["name", "age", "position", "experience"];

// Loop over the objects in the array
info.forEach(function(obj){
  let output = ""; // Will hold the output for one object at a time
  
  // Loop over the key names in the array so we go in the desired order
  keyNames.forEach(function(key){
    // Build up the string with they key name and the key value
    output += key + ": " + obj[key] + " ";
  });
  
  console.log(output); // Write out the string for the object
});
```

Comment: this returns object's values (Jane, 35, manager), I need to access the keys (name, age, position).

Comment: @alia You don't want the values or you want both the key names and vales?

Comment: @alia  If you know the key names and you know the order that you want them, why do you need the program to return them?

Comment: key:values in objects are stored in different order, so in id-1 it's name: Jane, age: 35, in id-2 it's age 38, name: John, I need display values from objects in the same order as myString, so like this  "name, age,position, experience" so all objects (id-1, id-2, id-3) will have key:values in the same order ( first will be name:value, then age:value) and etc.

Comment: @alia My original code did that, but I've reworked it to show you the names as well as the values.

Comment: thank you for your help, I checked your function, console.log(output) does  display keys in correct order, how can I apply that output to objects' keys? so it console logs keys in correct order, but when I console.log(info) keys are not in correct order.