# TypeScript How To Loop Through Array Of Objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm currently busy with an Angular project where I receive an object containing an array of objects from an API.

"reportData" is the object being sent to the API as a parameter through my service.

Example of data sent back from the API:

[image: Example of data retrieved]

I want to loop through the array and push the product names to an array and the same with the averageQuantityOrdered but I don't know how to loop through the array and get the values.

One thing that is confusing me is that when you look at the attached screenshot it looks like the result is an object containing an array of objects. And I think that is why I can't loop through it, since technically its an object and not an array.

I tried something like this (retrievedData is the array of objects) but then I get the error "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined":

```
retrievedData: any;

this.retrievedData.array.forEach(element => {
          this.productNames.push(element.ProductName);
        });
```

I use a service to retrieve the data:

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {

    this.service.postReportData().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.retrievedData = res;
        console.log(this.retrievedData);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how is `retrievedData` being set? An http call? If its async, you would need to do this type of work within `subscribe`

Comment: @Ric I simply declared it as any. "retrievedData: any;"

Comment: How is it being set? Manually or through an api call?

Comment: @Ric I make use of the postReportData() function in my service to get the information. I then subscribe to the result and assign that result to retrievedData. I added that piece of code to my question.

Comment: so you can just do: `this.retrievedData.forEach(item => { })` within the subscribe. Assuming the data returned is not null / undefined

Comment: You could use JS `Array#map`. Do this _inside_ the subscription: `this.productNames = res.reportData.map((data: any) => data.ProductName);`. You cannot do it outside the subscription since you never know when the observable will emit aka it's asynchronous. Learn more about async data in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921) post.

Comment: @Ric I tried that and I got the following error "ERROR TypeError: this.retrievedData.forEach is not a function"

Comment: @Ric One thing that is confusing me is that when you look at the attached screenshot it looks like the result is an object containing an array of objects. And I think that is why I can't loop through it, since technically its an object and not an array.

Comment: Check out this:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916461/12113049

Comment: what you see in the screenshot is an object with element named `reportData` which is an array of objects. `type Items = {ProductName: string; AverageQuantityOrdered: number; ProductOrders: unknown[]; }`  `type RetrievedData = { reportData: Items[] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your useful comments!

I got it working with the following code:

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {
    this.service.postReportData().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.retrievedData = res;

        this.retrievedData.reportData.forEach(function (item) {
          console.log(item);
          console.log(item.ProductName);
          console.log(item.AverageQuantityOrdered);
        });

      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

  }
```

Since reportData contained the array of objects I had to loop through that and not retrievedData.

Once again thanks to everyone, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

so what you receive is the an object containing array of objects

your `res` should be of type

```js
type Item = {
  ProductName: string;
  AverageQuantityOrdered: number;
  ProductOrders: unknown[];
}

type RetrievedData = {
  reportData: Item[];
}
```

so you can set `RetrievedData` as a type to your `retrievedData` variable

```js
retrievedData: RetrievedData
```

instead of `any`

and then `retrievedData.reportData` will give you the array.