# Iterate through array of objects,not giving required output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

given code

```
    [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "text_name": "test",
            "text_url": "https://www.news18.com/topics/gold-prices/1",
            "is_new": "1"
          },
          {
            "text_name": "test2",
            "text_url": "https://www.news18.com/topics/gold-prices/2",
            "is_new": "0"
          }
        ],
        "slug": "bollywood",
        "heading": "testing",
        "status": "1",
        "is_open_new": "1",
        "order_data": "2",
        "section_dropdown": "bollywood"
      }
    ]
```

I want to iterate through this given code snippet and get the data.

```
const trendingTopicsData = trendingTopics.data
```

but this is showing null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties)

Comment: `trendingTopics[0].data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object in the snippet is an array, first you have to get the index of the item you want to work with (in this case the first item — index 0). Then you can iterate through the `data` array however you want (loop, `forEach`, `map` *etc.*).

Try:

```
const trendingTopicsData = trendingTopics[0].data
```

Here it is as a runnable snippet:

```js
const trendingTopics = [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "text_name": "test",
          "text_url": "https://www.news18.com/topics/gold-prices/1",
          "is_new": "1"
        },
        {
          "text_name": "test2",
          "text_url": "https://www.news18.com/topics/gold-prices/2",
          "is_new": "0"
        }
      ],
      "slug": "bollywood",
      "heading": "testing",
      "status": "1",
      "is_open_new": "1",
      "order_data": "2",
      "section_dropdown": "bollywood"
    }
  ]

// Get trending topics data array
const trendingTopicsData = trendingTopics[0].data;
console.log("Data array:", trendingTopicsData)

// Iterate through each of the items in the data array
trendingTopicsData.forEach((dataItem, index) => console.log(`Data item #${index}:`, dataItem));
```

Comment: @navdhiman ... The OP'S own question was ... _**"Iterate through array of objects [...]"**_ and not _"How to access the sole first item of an array?"_

Answer (score 1):

The object you are trying to access is inside an array. You will have to loop through the array

```
trendingTopics.forEach(topic => {
  // do something with topic.data
})
```

Comment: @navdhiman ... The above answer provides a solution to what the OP actually did ask for ... _**"Iterate through array of objects [...]"**_ .